# How to server-side render a specific route in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, react-dom, react-dom-server

I would like to server-side render only a specific route in React. For example, `/home` should be client-side rendered, but `/post` should be server-side rendered.

The `/post` route receives a post ID as a parameter(using `react-router`) and fetches the content from a database server.

Is their any way I can server-side render **only a specific page/route** using `react-dom server`?

Comment: No, `react-router-dom` is client side routing. You'll need something like Nextjs to do any server-side routing/rendering. Is there an issue with having the `"/post"` route's component make an API call?

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be handled by the middleware and stored there to minimize api calls. The Front end should render based on that data.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach is to use built version of your react within express.js server. So let's say you have your built version of your react inside `build` directory :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("/post",function(req,res) { 
   console.log(req); // Do your stuff for post route
});

app.use("/",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/build")));
app.use("/*",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/build"))); // Handle react-router

const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on 8080");
});
```